# Homology of an attaching map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute the reduced homology groups with coefficients $A$, where $A$ is an abelian group, of the following space: $M_k = S^1 \bigcup_{\partial D^2} D^2$ where $D^2$ is the 2-disk, $S^1$ is the unit circle and $M_k$ is the space obtained by attaching a 2-cell to $S^1$ with attaching map $d_k : S^1 \rightarrow S^1$, s.t. $z \mapsto z^k$. So far I was wondering wether if there is a way to relate $M_k$ with the mapping cone $C_{d_k}= \frac {S^1 \sqcup S^1} { (z,0) \sim (z',0) ; (z,1) \sim d_k(z)} $. The motivation for it is that I know the corresponding long exact sequence in reduced homology of the mapping cone, so would be then easy to compute the reduced homology group of $M_k$. If this idea is wrong could I please have any other hint?

Comment: Do you know cellular homology? Because in that case, this shouldn't be too hard, and you should just compute the boundary map explicitly.

Comment: I still did not do the cellular homology, this I will learn probably in the next lessons.

Comment: However, what I know is that the induced homomorphism in homology of the d_k map is just given by multiplication with k

Comment: Then you know what the homology in degree $2$ is. Now, how about degree one?

Comment: should be the isomorphic to the coefficient group A ?

Comment: What are the cycles? What are the boundaries?

Comment: I don't know... if you have an answer I would appreciate it